# How could we run the Kafka example in the official Spark project?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I try to run the simple Kafka example in Spark project.

The spark built properly, so I can run most of the examples, except this Kafka example.

When I run the following command:

```
bin/run-example streaming.JavaDirectKafkaWordCount localhost:9092 test
```

I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka010/LocationStrategies
```

Any idea how could we run the Kafka Example properly?

(Kafka client running on port `9092`. Using the latest Spark and Kafka, and Java 8)

Comment: same problem, if you find a solution...

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWTQQ_2.0.0/solnguide/c_trd_trbls_java.langnoclassdeffounderrororg.html

Comment: Have you found `kafka010` jar on the Spark library folder?

Answer (score 0):

In my project, finally I connected together Kafka and Spark properly. I realised, using the `local` mode in Spark script is quite useful during development. Much easier to debug and practice.

You can find a detailed, dockerized implementation here: https://github.com/zoltan-nz/kafka-spark-project

Related notes: https://github.com/zoltan-nz/kafka-spark-project/blob/master/SparkStreamer/README.md#experiment-06---using-local